# java reading a formatted text file, store into arraylist and comparing info with a given command line args

Tags: java, arraylist, command-line-arguments

I am very new to java and I have a question on I/O.
Basically I have a file with a specific format.

```
a 7 a
b 2 b
c 6 c
d 5 d
e 4 e
```

What the program need to do is to read each line, store the integer field only in a ArrayList.

Then given in a command line arguments, the program should be able to answer how many letters that the integers equals to, or greater than the command line args.

For example, if the command line arguments is 5, the return answer should be 2.

What I have done in the following code is just to read each line with Scanner and store all information into ArrayList. I know it is quite far away from the requirements because I got stuck on how to store the integers fields only into the ArrayList as well as the command line args part.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestArrayList
{
    private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                list.add(s.next());             
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the argument from command line, you can get it from `args` from your `main(String[] args)` method arguments.

It is array of String, command line parameters read one by one separate by space.

In this problems, you should not store an `ArrayList` of integer, cause it contains String. But you can get Integer by convert from String by this method `Integer.parseInt("yourstring number")`

In my opinion, you should implement your own `compare` method to compare your `arg` and formatted input, it it you may specify `"a" > "b"` or whatever you need.

Hope this help!

Comment: so for the above example, how can I specifically store only the integer value on each line into arraylist? sorry, I am still confused.

Comment: you may use this inside your while loop `try{ Integer integer = Integer.parse(s); list.add(integer)}catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("not a number");}` to parse all the input to integer then put it into your `arraylist`, and of course if `Integer.parseInt("a or something not a number")` exception will be thrown and it will not be added to `integer arraylist`. Is this what you need?